# Where should I add a complex type element in this an XSD Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm working on a XSD Schema, I've been asked to add a new complex type on the concepts node, it looks like this:

```
 <xs:element name="Conceptos">                  
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Concepto" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:complexType>    
                        <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:element name="InformacionAduanera" type="cfdi:t_InformacionAduanera" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">                                           
                                </xs:element>
                                <xs:element name="CuentaPredial" minOccurs="0">
                                    <xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:documentation>Nodo opcional para asentar el número de cuenta predial con el que fue registrado el inmueble, en el sistema catastral de la entidad federativa de que trate.</xs:documentation>
                                    </xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:attribute name="numero" use="required">
                                            <xs:annotation>
                                                <xs:documentation>Atributo requerido para precisar el número de la cuenta predial del inmueble cubierto por el presente concepto en caso de recibos de arrendamiento.</xs:documentation>
                                            </xs:annotation>
                                            <xs:simpleType>
                                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                    <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                                                    <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                                </xs:restriction>
                                            </xs:simpleType>
                                        </xs:attribute>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>

                        </xs:choice>                                        
                            <xs:attribute name="cantidad" use="required">                                       
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                                        <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:attribute>
                            <xs:attribute name="unidad" use="optional">                                 
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:attribute>
                            <xs:attribute name="noIdentificacion" use="optional">                                       
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:attribute>
                            <xs:attribute name="descripcion" use="required">                                        
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:attribute>
                            <xs:attribute name="valorUnitario" type="cfdi:t_Importe" use="required">

                            </xs:attribute>
                            <xs:attribute name="importe" type="cfdi:t_Importe" use="required">

                            </xs:attribute>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```

This part of the XSD validates the following fragment of an XML

```
<cfdi:Conceptos>
<cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1.0" noIdentificacion="15" descripcion="Autotransporte terrestre de bienes" valorUnitario="10" importe="10" />
   <cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1.0" noIdentificacion="19" descripcion="PF a PM Retencion 2/3 IVA" valorUnitario="10" importe="10">
<cfdi:InformacionAduanera numero="123456" fecha="2011-07-13" aduana="Nuevo Laredo"/>
</cfdi:Concepto>
```

So what I want to do is to add a new element, so the xml look like this:

```
<cfdi:Conceptos>
<cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1.0" noIdentificacion="15" descripcion="Autotransporte terrestre de bienes" valorUnitario="10" importe="10" />
   <cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1.0" noIdentificacion="19" descripcion="PF a PM Retencion 2/3 IVA" valorUnitario="10" importe="10">
<cfdi:InformacionAduanera numero="123456" fecha="2011-07-13" aduana="Nuevo Laredo"/>
<cfdi:OptDetail name="TransID" value="34545" />
<cfdi:OptDetail name="Purchase" value="8745" />
<cfdi:OptDetail name="StoreID" value="1" />
<cfdi:OptDetail name="someName" value="SomeValue" />
<cfdi:OptDetail name="XXXX" value="YYYY" />
.
.
.
N
</cfdi:Concepto>
```

As you can see, I want to add a new element (optDetail) **for each Concepto** with minOccurs = 0 and maxOccurs= unbouded.It's almost the same thing as the InformacionAduanera node (I don't see the point of showing here the definition of this type) but, InformacionAduanera is under a Choice restriction, .

So what I did, is I defined my type first

```
<xs:complexType name="optDetail">       
    <xs:attribute name="name" use="required">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="value" use="required">          
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
```

I tried to add in to the XSD but without success, I got errors like the element node is misplaced or or too many occurrences for the element tag, so the question is where should I put it to validate my the xml shown above???

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your optDetail complex type is added under the xs:schema element (must be global, since it is named). The answer is shown below (I've removed content for brevity).

```
<xs:element name="Conceptos">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Concepto" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:element name="InformacionAduanera" type="cfdi:t_InformacionAduanera" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                            <xs:element name="CuentaPredial" minOccurs="0">...</xs:element>
                        </xs:choice>
                        <xs:element name="OptDetail" type="cfdi:optDetail" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="cantidad" use="required">
                        ...
                    </xs:attribute>
                    ...
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="optDetail"> 
    ...
</xs:complexType>
```